# Python String replacement in file

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently trying to generate a set of models that are specified in a text-file in the following syntax:

```
pn [BM1_100_Token]

constants:

places:
    P0 = 1;
    P1 = 0;
    [...]
    P14 = 2;
    P15 = 0;
    P16 = 0;
    P17 = 0;
    [...]

transitions:
    T0 :  : [P0 - 1] & [P1 + 1];
    T1 :  : [P1 - 1] & [P2 + 1] & [P3 + 1];
[...]
```

There may be zero occurences of Px = 2 which I want to modify:
I want to change all the occurences to a value Y and then save the file under a new name: BMz_Y_Token.txt

I figured this would be fairly simple via Python and Regular expressions but I'm kinda stuck at the moment since this is my first real experience with python.

My regular expression would be something like:

```
regex = re.compile(" = 2;")
```

I'm also able to get a list of files from a directory and split the filename So I get several different parts:

```
fileParts[1] = BMx
fileParts[2] = Y
fileParts[3] = Token.txt
```

So what I need to do now is:

1. Open the first file in fileList
2. Replace all occurences of " = 2;" to " = currentValue;"
3. Save to BMx_currentValue_Token.txt
4. currentValue++
5. If currentValue <= 999, goto step 2
6. Repeat from step 1 for the next File in fileList
7. If fileList.next == null -> We're done

So the result would be 999 variations for each file in a directory.
Any thoughts on how I would do this with Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For no 1, please explain what is fileList. I'd guess it is a list of file names (?).

For no 2, you do not need regular expression.  Just use the string method `.replace(' = 2;',' = currentValue;')`.

For numbers 4, 5, 6 and 7, you can use a `for` loop with a `range`. Remember in python `range(1000)` will yield integers from 0 to 999.

So from what you wrote (I assumed python2):

```
currentValue = 0
inpFileName = fileList[0]  # ?
for currentValue in range(1000):
  inpFile = open( inpFileName, 'r' )
  outFile = open( 'BMx_%d_Token.txt' % currentValue, 'w' )
  for inpLine in inpFile:
    outLine = inpLine.replace( ' = 2;', ' = %d;' % currentValue )
    outFile.write( outLine )
  inpFile.close()
  outFile.close()
```

I don't know if it is exactly what you want, but it should give you a good start.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot and was so much simpler than the things I tried. Just to clear this up:The fileList was indeed a list of files I retreived from a directory listing.